# Firefox doesn't want to execute

Tags: bash, path, firefox, bashrc

I removed previous version of firefox and I downloaded the 45.3.0esr.
I moved it to /home/user/firefox. Obviusly, if I type:

```
firefox
```

It raises:

```
bash: /usr/bin/firefox: No such file or directory
```

So I changed .bashrc and .bash_profile adding this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/firefox/"
```

But the problem persist.. in fact:

```
firerox
```

Raises always the same error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/firefox: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? I know I can just open it typing ./home/user/firefox/firefox-bin but I need to open with firefox command cause another program requires that (selenium).

I'm running ArchLinux.

Comment: What happens if you type `hash -r`, or logout and login again?  Do you have any aliases?

Comment: `export PATH="/home/user/bin/override/:$PATH:/home/user/bin"`, then put most of your own bins in `/home/user/bin` and ones to override system, in `/home/user/bin/override`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying `PATH` will not solve the problem.  The error message says it is looking for a specific pathname.  You could appease it by doing

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

assuming that "firefox" in your home-directory is

1. a filename, and
2. there is no dangling symbolic link `/usr/bin/firefox`
3. has no other dependencies...

The comment about `/home/user/firefox/firefox-bin` indicates that "firefox" is a directory, so...

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/firefox/firefox-bin /usr/bin/firefox
```

seems to be what you might want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I just used firefox package different architecture. My system is x64, I tried used 386 firefox package.